# Embedding javascript into an application (like Lua)

Tags: javascript, c++, lua, v8

I do a lot of web-related work with Javascript (some mundane web app stuff, some bleeding-edge software renderer/WebGL stuff), and I also have game-related projects which I code mostly in C++.

I have intended for the C++ bits use Lua to accomplish dynamic scripting functionality, but I am starting to wonder if it may serve me well to somehow embed a Javascript engine into my codebase so as to minimize the amount of context-switching I do, because it is going to make me cringe if the time comes that I find myself needing to port Lua code to JS or port JS code to Lua.

The V8 Javascript engine is embeddable and everything for a desktop C++ application and that'd be the end of it but the monkey wrench in this situation here is the problem of never being able to get V8 for a submission to the iOS App Store.

This leads me down quite a different path. What I wonder now is whether it will be possible to use `JavaScriptCore` to basically replace what I would use Lua for.

Comment: "never being able to get V8 for a submission to the iOS App Store." Why? Is this a technical or legal issue?

Comment: Considering that Google has released Chrome for iOS and it uses UIWebView rather than V8 it's clear Apple will not approve V8. Whether it is simply based on the JIT & marking pages executable issue or not is up for debate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just as a side note to this old question: [Apple has made JavaScriptCore a public API in IOS 7](http://blog.bignerdranch.com/3784-javascriptcore-and-ios-7/) so it could be used for dynamic scripting or other application logic.

Answer (score 2):

Awesome! Somebody has already [done this](http://www.phoboslab.org/log/2011/04/ios-and-javascript-for-real-this-time/).